# Why basename can not be used for a variable?

Tags: bash

I have the following shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$(basename $(pwd))"
MYDIR= "$(basename $(pwd))"
echo "this is ${MYDIR}"
```

When I execute it I got

```
mydirectory
./test.sh: line 4: mydirectory: command not found
this is
```

so eventhough the first line gets my current directory somehow this cannot be assigned to a variable

Why?? and how can I assign correctly the current directory to a variable (not the complete path)

EDIT: After I tried Gilles Quenot answer that works! (Thanks!) I tried mine with a small variation

```
#!/bin/bash
    
echo "$(basename $(pwd))"
MYDIR="$(basename $(pwd))"
echo "this is ${MYDIR}"
```

and now it works! turns out I should not put spaces around the "="!

Comment: https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @KansaiRobot : The middle line tells bash to execute as command the stdout of `basename`. Since `basename $(pwd)` obvioulsy outputs the string _mydirectory_, you ask for _mydirectory_ be executed, and this doesn't work.

Comment: @user1934428 How can I get then the current directoy not executed but as a string?

Comment: Just assign it to a variable, as you do it now anyway after having edited in your post (removing the space). Note that a general invocation of a command _COMMAND_ looks like `VAR1=VALUE1 VAR2=VALUE2... COMMAND PAR....`, so in your first attempt, you have set _MYDIR_ to the empty value and then executed _mydirectory_ as a command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- when you have shell errors, **always** check your script on https://shellcheck.net/
- never put spaces around `=` in shell
- for `dir` name, use `dirname`
- avoid using **UPPER CASE** variables, they are reserved for system use
- better use already configured `$PWD` variable:
  :

```
echo "$(basename "$PWD")"
mydir="$(dirname "$PWD")"
echo "this is $mydir"
```

Comment: `echo "${PWD##*/}"` `mydir="${PWD%/*}"`

Comment: OP seems to discover the shell, parameter expansions seems a bit too early

Comment: Regarding `reserved for system use`, why we see ORACLE_HOME, JAVA_HOME... ?

Comment: These are SYSTEM wide variables configurable per user

Comment: Thanks. I tried your shell and unfortunately it does not work. Result: `mydirectory` and `this is /absolute/path/before/my/directory`   However if I replace dirname for basename it works! (I dont understand why though but thanks!)

Comment: Oracle has many upper case variables, are they all `SYSTEM wide` ?

Comment: Oracle vars are for the system. User defined vars should be lower case, not mandatory, but a good practice